# Segmentation fault using tf.RunOptions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am developing a fairly big model and I need to use `tf.RunOptions` or other debuggers to slim a little my code because I'm getting OOM errors with really small batch sizes. But I get a segfault after using `tf.RunOptions`.

I don't believe it's a model problem, because also the following code will give problems (while the same code without the `runopt` is working):

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import tensorflow.keras.models as mm
    import tensorflow.keras.layers as ll
    import numpy as np

    model = mm.Sequential([
        ll.Dense(27,input_shape=(1,)),
        ll.Activation('relu'),
        ll.Dense(27),
        ll.Activation('softmax')
        ])

    runopt = tf.RunOptions(report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom = True)

    model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
                  loss='mean_squared_error',
                  metrics=['accuracy'],
                  options=runopt)

    a = np.zeros(27)*10

    model.fit(a,a,epochs=10)
```

Got the same error on Linux 18.04 (tensorflow-gpu installed with pip, `tf version 1.13.1`, `python version 3.6.7`, `CUDA 9.1.85`, `GeForce GTX 980 4GB)` and on `macOS 10.12.6` (tensorflow-cpu installed with pip, `tf version 1.13.1`, `python version 3.7.2`)

Answer (score 1):

To use `tf.RunOptions`, you have to use **also** `tf.RunMetadata()`!

This fixed this issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.models as mm
import tensorflow.keras.layers as ll
import numpy as np

model = mm.Sequential([
    ll.Dense(27,input_shape=(1,)),
    ll.Activation('relu'),
    ll.Dense(27),
    ll.Activation('softmax')
    ])

runopt = tf.RunOptions(report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom = True)
runmeta = tf.RunMetadata()

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'],
              options=runopt,
              run_metadata=runmeta)
```